# Using streams to pipe data in node.js

Tags: node.js, stream

Setup: I am reading data from a database and emailing the dataset as a CSV file. The data get read in chunks of 500 rows, and I'm using [ya-csv](https://github.com/koles/ya-csv) to write the records as a CSV to a stream. I then want to use [mailgun-js](https://github.com/1lobby/mailgun-js) to email the file as an attachment.

### Option 1 (what I don't want to do):

1. create temp file;
2. create write stream to that file;
3. write all CSV records;
4. read all of it back into memory to attach to an email;

### Option 2 (what I want to do but don't quite know how to):

1. create a writable stream;
2. create a readable stream;
3. somehow pipe the writes from (1) into (2);
4. pass the writable stream to ya-csv;
5. pass the readable stream to mailgun;
6. fetch data and write to the write stream until there's no more data;
7. end the write stream, thus ending the read stream and sending the email.

I've been reading https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook and https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html, and the problem is that I can't use `writable.pipe(readable);`.

I have tried using a `Duplex` stream (i.e. both the write and read streams are just Duplex streams) but this doesn't work as Duplex is an abstract class and I'd have to implement several of the linking parts.

**Question:** how do I use streams to link up this writing of CSV records to streaming an attachment to mailgun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't overthink it, `mailgun-js` can take a stream as attachment, it can be as easy as:

```
var csv = require('csv');
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

// this will stream some csv
var file = myDbStream.pipe(csv.stringify());

var data = {
    from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
    to: 'serobnic@mail.ru',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!',
    attachment: file // attach it to your message, mailgun should deal with it
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

I don't know what your Db is, maybe the driver already has a support for streams or you'll have to feed `csv` manually (can be done very easily with `event-stream`).

**Edit**

`ya-csv` seems to not be able to be piped easily, `csv` works better.

Comment: That seems to work, except that I am using `mailgun.Attachment` to create the attachment, and there nothing is attached to the emails I receive. I have logged from `data` events on the stream, and the data are definitely correct, but the emails come through w/o an attachment.

Comment: From the doc, they require a `contentType` and `knownLength` for a stream and **If an attachment object does not satisfy those valid conditions it is ignored.**